# Gluu - How to write/export new local Gluu users to Active Directory LDAP?

Tags: gluu

I'm new to Gluu and have a question regarding import/export sync with LDAP (active directory).  I have a server setup locally and am able to successfully import/sync Users from my Active Directory into Gluu locally via LDAP Cache just fine.

My question is, how can I can configure Gluu so that any new users I create locally within Gluu and any AD Imported users whose attributes I update, also get exported/sync'd back to my Active Directory?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Apache Directory Studio` and export/import any entry you want to manage. Take a look to this section of the documentation:

https://gluu.org/docs/gluu-server/user-management/local-user-management/#import-people-in-oxtrust

Also if it's not clear at all, consider openning a question in the Gluu support platform.
https://support.gluu.org/